# regex pattern 1,3,30,32,40-50,60

Tags: regex

Regex pattern that accepts this example

```
1,3,30,32,40-50,60
```

Comment: Please have a read here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then update your post by pressing the edit link and add more information. As it stands what you are asking is not clear.  Include tags that indicate what editor, OS or RDBMS you are using as well. Show a before and after example and sample text that can be used to illustrate your problem and what you expect to get from the answer.

Comment: Unless you have some examples of what else to match and what not to match, there are essentially an infinite number of regexes that will match that string.

Answer (score 1):

this regex

```
\b(1|3|30|32|50|60)\b|4[0-9]\b
```

matches numbers of this comma separated string:

```
1,3,30,32,40-50,60
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `((?:\d+)(?:-\d+)?)(?:,|$)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PNtdWJ/1)